# I want to configur nginx to open the two projects on one domain with different urls

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have a project hosted on `blog.example.com` and another project on `example.com`. Both are multilingual projects by first URL segment e.g. `blog.example.com/fr/foo/bar` and `example.com/fr/foo/bar` but for default language, I don't have a segment `/fr/`, e,g. `example.com/foo/bar` and `blog.example.com/foo/bar`. Now I want to open `blog.example.com` using `example.com/blog/foo/bar` and `example.com/fr/blog/foo/bar` and keep working main project on `example.com`.

I have tried like this but it doesn't work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location ~ ^\/(?<lang>[a-z]+)/blog(.*) {
        rewrite ^\/(?<lang>[a-z]+)/blog(.*)$ /blog$2 break;
        proxy_pass http://blog.example.com/$lang;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?<lang>[a-z]+)(/.*)?$ {
        rewrite ^/(?<lang>[a-z]+)(/.*)?$ $2 break;
        proxy_pass http://main_project;
    }

    location /blog {
        proxy_pass http://blog.example.com;
    }
}
```

In the nginx log:

```
2023/08/24 07:41:27 [notice] 1075001#1075001: signal process started
2023/08/24 07:44:19 [notice] 1075803#1075803: signal process started
```

> Languages can be a lot.